# Local static pointer variable is not thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, log4cxx

At my server module, sometimes log4cxx library made it crash.

It's because ...

```
LevelPtr Level::getTrace() {
   static LevelPtr level(new Level(Level::TRACE_INT, LOG4CXX_STR("TRACE"), 7));
   return level;
}
```

static LevelPtr returns null ptr.

I tested following code.

```
int start_flag = 0;

class test_dummy {
public:
    int mi;
    test_dummy() : mi(1)
    { 
        std::cout << "hey!\n"; 
    }
    static test_dummy* get_p() 
    { 
        static test_dummy* _p = new test_dummy();
        return _p;
    }
};

void thread_proc()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (start_flag == 0)
    {
        i++;
    }
    if (test_dummy::get_p() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "error!!!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "mi:" << test_dummy::get_p()->mi << "\n";
    }
}

void main()
{
    boost::thread *pth_array[5] = {0,};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        pth_array[i] = new boost::thread(thread_proc);
    }
    start_flag = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        pth_array[i]->join();
    }
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

It's really thread-unsafe, but I'm curious about why get_p() return null pointer not another allocated address.

It's because the value was set to 0 while one is doing new() operation?

Comment: Without disassembling the code it will be hard to know why and I can't do that at the moment... Undefined behavior in c++03 so nothing in the standard will tell you why. In c++11 though this is thread safe.

Comment: What multithreading are you using? POSIX? WIN32? What platform? What compiler? (Or is this c++11 threading?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz His example uses Boost threads.

Comment: I tested at windows 7 / WIN32 / MSVC10 (VS2010) / c++03. I missed my test environment, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition in this code that the compiler provides:

```
if (!level_initialized)
{
    level_initialized = 1;
    level = new Level(...);
}
return level;
```

(It doesn't look EXACTLY like that - it's more complex, but I think you get the general idea)

In clang++ 3.5, it seems like there are locks to prevent this sort of race, but without actually looking at the code generated by your compiler, it's impossible to say exactly what is going on. But I suspect that this is what happens.

Here's what clang++ 3.5 generates (minus some clutter)

```
_Z8getTracev:                           # @_Z8getTracev
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $32, %rsp
    cmpb    $0, _ZGVZ8getTracevE5level       # Guard variable
    jne .LBB0_4
    leaq    _ZGVZ8getTracevE5level, %rdi
    callq   __cxa_guard_acquire
    cmpl    $0, %eax
    je  .LBB0_4
.Ltmp0:
    movl    $4, %eax
    movl    %eax, %edi
    callq   _Znwm                            # new
.Ltmp1:
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)         # 8-byte Spill
    jmp .LBB0_3
.LBB0_3:                                # %invoke.cont
    leaq    _ZGVZ8getTracevE5level, %rdi
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax         # 8-byte Reload
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rcx         # 8-byte Reload
    movl    $0, (%rcx)
    movq    %rax, _ZZ8getTracevE5level
    callq   __cxa_guard_release
.LBB0_4:                                # %init.end
    movq    _ZZ8getTracevE5level, %rax
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

I modified the code to use `Level` as an `int`, etc, so it's simpler than the code you'd get from exactly the code you posted.

Comment: That's not (and never has been) a legal implementation of local static variable initialization.  Even in a single threaded environment: if the constructor of `Level` exits with an exception, the local static must be considered not initialized, and later calls to the function must try to initialize it.

Comment: My comment refers to your summary example, of course, and not to the generated code from clang++.  The generated code from clang is simply not thread safe, since it contains unprotected accesses to `_ZGVZ8getTradevE5level`.  (This looks like a botched attempt to implement the double checked locking algorithm.  For double checked locking to work, all accesses to the pointer must be atomic, in the new sense of atomic.)

Comment: -1 doesn't seem to really answer the question - especially about the sample code returning a null ptr.

Comment: @Elemental It does in a way; he's suggesting that it's due to a compiler error.

Comment: Right, I made the sample very simplistic to show the issue in itself, not really covering bases such as exceptions - is an exception really believed to be the issue here? I'm not saying it's impossible, but to me, it seems more likely that the compiler is simply generating bad code...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say much, since the code clearly has undefined
behavior, but the standard does require `level` to be
initialized to a null pointer before `get_p` is called.  And in
order to ensure that the local static is initialized exactly
once, the compiler more or less has to add an extra flag;
something like:

```
static test_dummy* _p = nullptr;
static bool isInitialized = false;
if ( !isInitialized ) {
    _p = new test_dummy();
    isInitialized = true;
}
```

(In fact, of course, the initializations shown above are the
zero initialization , which occurs before anything else.  And
a clever compiler could realize that the explicit initialization
which occurs the first time through cannot result in `_p` being
a null pointer, and use `_p` as the control variable.)

The above isn't thread safe; in order to make it thread safe,
the entire sequence must be protected.  (There are also more or
less complicated tricks to avoid the need for a full mutex, but
in all cases, *all* accesses to `isInitialized` must be atomic.)

If the sequence isn't protected, the order another thread sees
the writes isn't defined.  So some thread is seeing
`isInitialized` as true, but still seeing the null pointer in
`_p`.